# Trim the content of system()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out all the users in active directory using system("dsquery user"); in php, my problem is getting it trimmed down so I have an array containing all the users and nothing else, atm this is my code:

```
<?php
$test = system("dsquery user");
$teste = explode('CN=', $test);
print_r($teste);
$user = trim($teste[1], ",");
echo "<br \>" . $user;
?>
```

I can only fetch one user atm because the explode deletes everything else..
Any help is appreciated, basically what I wan't to have in the end is something like this:

```
$user[0] = Administrator
$user[1] = kbgrt
$user[2] = asdasd
```

This is the output:

"CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local" "CN=doctor.scripto,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" –

I hope you understand otherwise comment and I'll try to explain in another way.

Comment: Explode should not "delete" anything inside the array. The only thing which would be removed is every instance of **CN=**, which is your split dilema. How does the array look before exploding?

Comment: What does the output of `dsquery user` look like?

Comment: "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"
"CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"
"CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local"
"CN=doctor.scripto,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"

Answer (score 0):

Its not always easy to parse output from commands, if they are not designad for it. However a good start is to try to simplify it as much as possible and see patterns. However hope the code bellow will work for you I try to commented it as much as possible.

I have started with your output from system("dsquery user");

```
$test = '"CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=Domain,DC=local" "CN=doctor.scripto,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=local"';
```

To make it easier I remove spaces and " from the string

```
$test = str_replace(' ', ',', $test);
$test = str_replace('"', '', $test);
```

Now we are ready to split the string on , so we get an array $teste that has elements that starts with LDIF values("DC=" or "CN=" in our case)

```
$teste = explode(',', $test);
```

Since some users are unwanted I add an array to exclude them. Also create an array $users to keep the result.

```
$users = array();
$exclude_users = array("Users", "doctor.scripto");
```

Then its just to iterate over array and split each element, so we get the LDIF part in position 0 and name in position 1. Add the name, if position 0 is equal to CN and name in position 1 is not in the list of excluded users.

```
foreach ($teste as $value) {
    $data = explode('=', $value);
    if($data[0] == 'CN' && !in_array($data[1], $exclude_users)) {
       $users[] = $data[1];
    }
}

print_r($users);
```

Here is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Administrator
    [1] => Guest
    [2] => krbtgt
)
```